# What does this line mean : "The man's high tone spread throughout the spacious bar"

Tags: meaning, expressions

I am reading this light novel called GGO and in it I came across these lines:

> "AGI (Agility) being all powerful is just an illusion."
>
> The man's high tones spread throughout the spacious bar.

and I can't figure out what the second line means here.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the second line to the quote?  It isn't a complete-enough context for an answer.  Also, is there an online ref?  Is *Illusion* actually capitalized in original? [Please edit the question]

Comment: I think these lines are from the prologue of this site- http://gungaleonlinevmmorpg.blogspot.in/p/sword-art-onlinevolume-5-prologue.html

Comment: The phrase "high tones" refers to the pitch of the man's voice as he spoke; the bar is an establishment that sells liquor and other alcoholic beverages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a quote including the bit from the question, plus some later lines. [Source: a [gungaleonlinevmmorpg](http://gungaleonlinevmmorpg.blogspot.com/p/sword-art-onlinevolume-5-prologue.html) blog]

> “AGI(Agility) being all powerful is just an illusion!” 
>   The man’s high tones spread throughout the spacious bar.
>   “It is true that AGI is an important attribute as it determines firing speed and avoidance rate. These two factors could make you very strong, until now that is.”  [...]  That speech came from a player in the square holo-panel floating in the center of the dim shop. It was the net broadcast, [...] You could watch it in the real world from a television or a computer, but it was also broadcasted in many VRMMO worlds’ inns and bars simultaneously, [...]

From the extended context, it's clear that *bar* means a saloon or pub where alcohol is served.  There is a man speaking via a holo-panel, turned up loudly enough to be heard throughout a certain bar.  His voice is high-pitched, but I have the impression (from use of the word *tones*) it may be mellow enough for easy listening.